# Ubuntu 20.04. Two network cards. Netplan. Can't configure in parallel

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet, netplan

I have a problem. There is a server. It has two network cards installed.

Logically, one network card (enp4s0) for the Internet.

Second network card (enp2s5) for network users to access the server (server IP: 192.168.1.5).

The problem is my config only works for one network card.

When I change the metrics, only access from the network works, or access to the server from the Internet. I need everything to work in parallel.

Please tell me what is my mistake?

According to the configuration below, I can access the server, both from the Internet and from the local network, but users do not see it (since the metrics for **enp4s0** are lower than for **enp2s5**)

**Netplan**

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.222/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2]
    routes:
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 192.168.0.1
        metric: 1
    enp2s5:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.5/24]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.1.1
          metric: 2
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.2.1
          metric: 2
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
```

Comment: I assume `192.168.0.1`, `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.2.1` are gateway addresses. It seems odd that you only define one IP address for enp2s5 when there are 2 gateway addresses. Also, what if you define the metric with equal values?

Comment: Also you say that you can access the server from both LAN and WAN - then everything seems to be working - else please elaborate.

Comment: Hello Arthur! Yes, 192.168.0.1, 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.2.1 are SVI addresses.
I can access the server from the internet, the router redirects me to it.
My logic is this, enp4s0 for access from anywhere. enp2s5 for computers on the network that need access to the server at 192.168.1.5. Thanks!

Comment: And what's not working for you?

Comment: It's funny, but two network cards do not work at the same time, if metric 1 is in enp4s0, I can log into the server from the Internet, but local network users cannot log into server 192.168.1.5. Conversely, if metric 1 is assigned to enp2s5, I lose access, but local network users gain access to server 192.168.1.5.

Comment: And if both are `metric: 1`?

Comment: Then the Internet access starts to work intermittently (this can be seen by the ping to the address 8.8.8.8), and local users never get access to the server at 192.168.1.5

Answer (score 0):

Why do you configure default routes (to: 0.0.0.0/0) on both cards? This will not work correctly when both NICs are up and a connection is attempted from a non-local network. Most likely you will use the default route only on the NIC connected to the internet (enp4s0) and you will have to add explicit routes (192.168.1.0 and 192.168.2.0) to the local NIC's (enp2s5) IPs